# Force PascalCase when returning partial views with model from the mvc controller

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, system.text.json

I have an action method that returns a `Partialview("_partialViewName", partialViewModel)`. By default the serializer used by the asp.net core converts the property names to camelCase but I want it in PascalCase.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomer(int id)   
{
     var customer = GetCustomerFromDb(id);
     return PartialView("_CustomerPartialView", customer); 
}
```

The response is returned to an ajax method's `success` function in a JS file. All the model properties are in `camelCase` but I need them in `PascalCase`.

Using the JSON.Net (even tried System.Text.Json) as the serializer and don't want to set the setting options globally in ConfigureServices().  It needs to be in the controller itself.

Here is my settings config:

```
var serializerSettings = new SerializerSettings 
{
     ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
}
```

There are 4 overloads of the PartialView() method but none accepts Json Setting as an argument.

Any idea how I can force the serializer to use the PascalCase?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, when using Ajax to call the GetCustomer action method, it will return a partial view to the success function, and the view contains the html element and the related property value, and the related property name is PascalCase, [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAv3K.png), you can try to use F12 developer tools to check it.

I assume there might have an action/API method, which will return a list of Object. Then, when using JQuery ajax to call this method, the response data is camelCase, like this:

[image]

In this scenario, to make the response data's property name is PascalCase, you can return a json string in the action method, then in the success function, after getting the json string, you could use [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) method to convert the json string to the Object, code like this:

API method:

```
    [HttpGet("getAllStudent")]
    public string GetAllStudent()
    {
        var students = new List<StudentViewModel>()
        {
            new StudentViewModel(){ ID=101, Name="Tom", GPA="A"},
            new StudentViewModel(){ ID=102, Name="David", GPA="A"},
            new StudentViewModel(){ ID=103, Name="Jim", GPA="A"},
            new StudentViewModel(){ ID=104, Name="Vivian", GPA="A"},
            new StudentViewModel(){ ID=105, Name="Jack", GPA="A"},
        };

        //required System.Text.Json 
        var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(students);
        return jsonString;
    }
```

JQuery Ajax script:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/todo/getAllStudent',
            type: 'Get', 
            traditional: true,
            success: function (response) {
                //use JSON.parse() method to convert the json string to object.
                var result = JSON.parse(response);
                //then, you can dynamically add the html elements and render the data.
              
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            }
        });
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I would rather have asp.net process the view+model and return the html than manually doing it.  I wish they have an overload of `PartialView()` accepting json options.  I actually resolved my issue by adding the `JsonProperty` attribute for each property in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up annotating the properties in the model with `JsonProperty` attribute so the serializer respects the pascal casing in the model.

```
 public class Customer
 {
    [JsonProperty(nameof(Id))]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
 }
```

Apparently this overrides the camel casing default behavior in asp.net.

Comment: You have stated *. All the model properties are in camelCase*. Here your sample is in PascalCase. So, which one is correct?